how to fill top and bottom white spaces when coloring table cells
I was looking into an alternative, which preserve a table spacing without squeezing the content, and allows coloring a cell background filling it from top to bottom. I've tested the following:
\newcommand{\midsepremove}{\aboverulesep = 0mm \belowrulesep = 0mm}\midsepremove

which, however, has the exact issue I illustrated above... Is there another way to do so? Below, a MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme[width=0pt,height=.5in]{sidebar}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable,siunitx,multirow,booktabs}
\newcommand{\smallerbaseline}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\selectfont}

\definecolor{bground}{HTML}{005EB8}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=anti-flashwhite,bg=bground}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}
\tiny

\begin{longtable}{
    >{\smallerbaseline\bfseries} c 
        *{2}{S[table-format=5.0]
         S[table-format=5.0]
         S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\unit{\percent}]<{\unit{\percent}}
         S[table-format=5.0]
         S[table-format=5.0]}
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{10}{c}{\textbf{APPROACH}} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{linear reference}  
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{pangenome graph} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-11}

& {\textit{exp}} & {\textit{med}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{R\textsuperscript{2}}} & \textit{minQ} & \textit{MaxQ} & {\textit{exp}} & {\textit{med}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{R\textsuperscript{2}}} & \textit{minQ} & \textit{MaxQ} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}

tdOA1 & 62685 & \cellcolor{red!25}57826 & 46.18 & 45729 & 96452 & 58110 & \cellcolor{red!25}54272 & 46.18 & 45663 & 90268 \\
tdOA2 & 49041 & \cellcolor{red!25}46917 & 24.25 & 40837 & 63729 & 47796 & \cellcolor{red!25}46030 & 24.25 & 40525 & 60121 \\

\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


Have a look at tabularray

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I see, so there is no way around with longtable only; I will change the code accordingly, thanks a lot!

It isn't clear what you want to do but \smallerbaseline will do nothing at all in a c  column, perhaps you meant to put that before \begin{longtable} to affect the baseline in the table

the booktabs rules add vertical space if you don't want that use standard \hline

@DavidCarlisle Indeed, I tried removing it from there and nothing changed; thanks for the clarification. I will play with \booktabs as well; however, having other tables in the presentation I wish this to be more of a local setting for the specific example above.

You are already loading the tabularray package - you just need to use it, too.
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme[width=0pt,height=.5in]{sidebar}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{normal}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{caption}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{capcont}{normal}{}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tiny\centering
\begin{longtblr}{
  %  setting up columns
  columns={colsep+={-1pt}},
  column{2-3,5-8,10-Z} = {si={table-format=5.0}},
  column{4,9} = {si={table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\unit{\percent}}},
  % add some extra space between rows to show that the colour fills them completly
  rows={rowsep+={1pt}},
  % protect the header from siunitx
  row{1-3} = {guard,halign=c},
  % adding horizontal lines
  hline{1,Z} = {1pt},
  hline{2,4} = {2-Z}{0.2pt},
  hline{3} = {2-6}{rightpos = -1, endpos},
  hline{3} = {7-Z}{leftpos = -1, endpos},
  % fonts, colours, etc.
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
  row{3} = {font=\itshape},
  column{1} = {font=\bfseries,c},
  cell{4-Z}{3,8} = {red!25},
  cell{4-Z}{4,9} = {appto={\unit{\percent}}}
}
& \SetCell[c=10]{} APPROACH &&&&&&&&&\\
& \SetCell[c=5]{} linear reference &&&& 
& \SetCell[c=5]{} pangenome graph &&&&\\
& exp & med & R\textsuperscript{2} & minQ & MaxQ & exp & med & R\textsuperscript{2} & minQ & MaxQ \\
tdOA1 & 62685 & 57826 & 46.18 & 45729 & 96452 & 58110 & 54272 & 46.18 & 45663 & 90268 \\
tdOA2 & 49041 & 46917 & 24.25 & 40837 & 63729 & 47796 & 46030 & 24.25 & 40525 & 60121 \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



much appreciated. In the end, the best I could get on my own was filling the bottom white space; however, that came with the issue that the red filling “spilled” a little over the last \cmidrule... Very helpful to see how everything is done in one place, thanks again!

I was looking a bit into it but couldn't come up with a solution. I happen to use the dynablocks package which requires the \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}, this seems to bother some settings of longtblr. Essentially, I got the following — "Package tabularray Warning: Table width is too small, need 3.02118pt more!" and an overfull \hbox. Without the \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}, this warning disappear but I get: "LaTeX Error: Command \guillemetleft unavailable in encoding OT1." for all frames using dynablocks... To be noted none of them prevent compilation

however, I would like to better understand the source of this issue?

@Matteo You can avoid the overfull box by making the column spacing a tiny bit smaller, see my updated answer

wonderful, thanks again!
